# Can Neovim API get the text in command input area?

Tags: neovim, macos, vim-development

I'm developing a GUI client of Neovim, and looking for the way to get the text in command input area using msgpack-rpc.
I mean that the 'text in command input area' is the bottom of Neovim window. 
(Sorry, I'm not sure how to express it.)
[image]

Does Neovim have any APIs to get it like `buffer_get_line()`?

Comment: That is typically and variously called the (ex/colon) command line/prompt. I cannot remember what the documentation calls it, if it has a name, but I believe it to be simply the command line.

Comment: You’ll have the best luck getting this answered by neovim maintainers; I’d file an issue on their [github](https://github.com/neovim/neovim)

Comment: You can use getcmdline getcmdtype (see also getcmdpos if you want the cursor position)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/ui.txt

Attaching the ui by |nvim_ui_attach()| method with option `ext_cmdline=true',
then the cmdline_xxxx methods are callback from neovim.

Comment: If you're building a UI then `ext_cmdline` is the best solution. Otherwise you could also use the VimL `getcmdline()` function. E.g. `nvim_eval("getcmdline()")`